# How to clear output (not terminal) but in a gui

Tags: python, tkinter

Very new to python, I was scripting a lbs to kg converter, and want to know how to clear the output after receiving the answer, basically whenever I press the convert button it keeps giving output, and it will keep expanding the window.

```
def to_kg():
kg=float(entry1.get())/2.0462
labelanswer=tk.Label(root, text=(kg), bg='teal')
labelanswer.place(x=45,y=45)
labelanswer.pack()




import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import BOTTOM
from typing import Text

root=tk.Tk()

root.resizable(False, False)

root.title('Pounds to Kilograms')

canvas=tk.Canvas(root, height=150, width=200, bg='teal')

frame=tk.Frame(root, bg='white')
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1 rely=0.1)

entry1=tk.Entry(root)
canvas.create_window(200, 200, window=entry1)
entry1.place(x=40, y=50)

def to_kg():
    kg=float(entry1.get())/2.205
    labelanswer=tk.Label(root, text=(kg), bg='teal')
    labelanswer.place(x=45,y=45)
    labelanswer.pack()

labeltext=tk.Label(root, text='lbs to kg', bg='white')

button1=tk.Button(root, text="convert", command=to_kg)

button1.pack(side=BOTTOM)
canvas.pack()
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCuRe.png)
[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxJcQ.png)

Comment: Are you running this in a loop of some kind?

Comment: @RonBeyer I am not running this in a loop

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new label in each button click. This will create a new label as on your screenshot. Instead of creating new label, you should modify the answer label. So, there is only one `answerlabel`.

Here is the working solution.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import BOTTOM
from typing import Text

root=tk.Tk()

root.resizable(False, False)

root.title('Pounds to Kilograms')

canvas=tk.Canvas(root, height=150, width=200, bg='teal')

frame=tk.Frame(root, bg='white')
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

entry1=tk.Entry(root)
canvas.create_window(200, 200, window=entry1)
entry1.place(x=40, y=50)

labelanswer=tk.Label(root, bg='teal')
labelanswer.place(x=45,y=45)

def to_kg():
    kg=float(entry1.get())/2.205
    labelanswer['text'] = kg

labeltext=tk.Label(root, text='lbs to kg', bg='white')

button1=tk.Button(root, text="convert", command=to_kg)

button1.pack(side=BOTTOM)
canvas.pack()
labelanswer.pack()
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

line `labelanswer['text'] = kg` is a way to change your answer label.